# Upload csv file to mysql database error in sql syntax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, csv, mysqli

I have a piece of javascript that fetches a file and generates a name. This data gets put into a FormData object. This gets send by ajax to the server. See the javascript below:

```
function create_form_data(option_file_name){
  var file = $('#'+option_file_name.id).prop('files')[0];
  var form_data = new FormData(); 
  form_data.append('file', file);
  form_data.append('tblname', option_file_name.id.slice(12));
  send_ajax_request(form_data);

}

function send_ajax_request(pdata){
  $.ajax({
    url: "set_points_data.php",
    data: pdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    dataType: "text",
    type: 'post',
    success: function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(a,b,c){
      console.log(a);
      console.log(b);
      console.log(c);
    }
  });
}
```

Now in the set_points_data.php i do the following:

```
include 'data.php';

if(isset($_FILES)){
    $data = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $db_name = mysqli_escape_string($conn, $_POST["tblname"]);
    return_ajax(create_table($conn, $db_name, $data));
}else{
    return_ajax("error");
}

function create_table($conn, $name, $data){
    send_sql($conn, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS domestic_data_strings.".$name."");
    send_sql($conn, "CREATE TABLE $name (options varchar(255));");
    send_sql($conn, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $data INTO TABLE $name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (options)");

    return $name;

}
```

But I keep getting the following error :

> Error: LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE column_age.csv INTO TABLE age FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '
>       ' (options)
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'column_age.csv INTO TABLE age FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' at line 1

I have no idea what is going wrong here :( I tried different `.csv` files, but that didnt make a difference. I checked if the table existed with the correct column what is also correct. Any help is greatly appreciated!

If more context is required please let me know!

Comment: I think the problem is in the point ".csv". Just try to escape it like that "filename\.csv"

Comment: even after escaping it still gives the same error... see updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you have to surround the file name in your query with single quotes: 
`send_sql($conn, "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $data . "' INTO TABLE $name FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (options)");`